# cannot get Facebook Session for login (FB PHP SDK 4.0.0)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

after various tries, i decided to write here my problem with FB PHP login with SDK 4.0.0.
The problem is that I cannot retrieve the session, and I don't know why.
My code (placed in a file named "social.php") is the follow:

```
session_start();    
define('fbsdk', "/fbsdk/src/Facebook/");
require __DIR__ . '/fbsdk/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

if(isset($_GET['login'])){
    if($_GET['login'] == "fb"){
        $appid = "677652872357474";
        $appsecret = "******";

        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appid, $appsecret);
        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/ffideasbox/');

        try{
            $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
        } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex){
            print_r($ex);
        } catch(Exception $ex){
            print_r($ex);
        }

        if(isset($session)){
            echo "Session defined: ".$session;
        } else {
            echo "Session not defined";
        }
    } elseif($_GET['login'] == "tw"){
    } elseif($_GET['login'] == "gp"){
    } else {
       ...
    }
} else {
    ....
}
?>
```

If I go to the documentation page of Session (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/4.0.0), it says me that I can get session by:

```
// If you already have a valid access token:
$session = new FacebookSession('access-token');

// If you're making app-level requests:
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
```

Eventually, which is the access token? And how can I get it?

Then, after have posted here, I added before the session TRY block, this other one:
            $session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

```
        try{
            $session->validate();
        } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        } catch(\Exception $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
```

But I still get the same message: "Session not defined" (wrote by me in the session IF block).

Could someone tell me more about the FBSDK? I read the documentation but I don't understand much.
Thank you all.

EDIT: I add also the "map" of the sdk folder

```
-mainfolder
|-fbsdk
 |-autoload.php
 |-src
  |-Facebook
   |-All the complete facebook sdk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After have looked for examples and more, I looked that I didn't had added the piece

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
```

in the isset($session) else. This because I didn't understand why it was needed and when the session is not defined, I didn't redirect anywhere.

```
if(isset($session)){
   echo "Session defined: ".$session;
} else {
   $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
   header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
```